# javascript onclick function works when parameter is integer but not string?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
echo '<a onclick="load_tags('.$list['id'].')"></a>'
```

when `list[id]` is a number, it works. but when `list[id]` is a word, it does not work. why?

below is some background on the function and what i am doing. although it is not necessary for the purposes of answering this question.

script

```
function load_tags(id){
        $.post('../php/tags/get_tags.php',{id:id},function(data){
            $('#tags_selected').text(data);
        });
    }
```

get_tags.php

```
$tag_id=$_POST['id'];
    echo $tag_id;
    $users_with_this_tag=show_all_users_with_this_tag($tag_id);
    if(count($users_with_this_tag)!=0){
            foreach($users_with_this_tag as $key => $list){
                echo $list['user_id'];
            }
    }else{
        echo'Nobody with this tag';
    }
```

Comment: do you get an error or `Nobody with this tag` ?

Comment: no i get Uncaught ReferenceError: running is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just surround `load_tags` argument with escaped single quotes:

```
echo '<a onclick="load_tags(\''.$list['id'].'\')"></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings should have quotes around them:

```
echo '<a onclick="load_tags(\"'.$list['id'].'\")"></a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Becouse it couses syntax error.
Calling JS function with int:

```
function(123) 
{
 ....
}
```

And with string:

```
function('foo') 
{
 ....
}
```

Without *'* it searches for variable under string name (if it's valid variable name).